# שליח-השליח: why the difference?

Tags: passover-seder-hagada

How come in the paragraph starting ויוציאנו ה' ממצרים… the first time the Hagaddah says ולא ע"י שליח, and the second time ולא השליח?

Comment: Which edition Haggada are you looking at?

Comment: Many editions have השליח in both and many have it in neither.

Comment: Keep in mind that in [Rabbinical] Mishnaic Hebrew there was a big mess caused by Aramaic lack of ה. Compare שבת הגדול. Many Sugiot of Shas are trying to interpret [mis]-use of ה in the Mishna, such as "האשה נקנית" or "הַמְקַדֵּשׁ אֶת הָאִשָּׁה"

Answer (score 1):

From memory (my grandchildren at the seder and from various haggador which I do not have with me). Hashem had appointed Moshe Rabbeinu as the shaliach to bring the Bnai Yisrael out of Mitzraim. When a shaliach is appointed, that agent is supposed to act on behalf of the one who appointed him (as Moshe acted in the previous 9 makos). However, in this final plague, Hashem acted explicitly and did not allow Moshe to be his agent, as he acted in the rest of the Exodus and as the leader in the desert. The other phrases also do not have the *hei hayediah* because Hashem did not appoint any being to act on his behalf.

The initial statement uses  ולא ע"י שליח (does not have the *hei hayediah*) because it is a basic statement of the general concept. as applied to the entire pasuk. That is He did not assign any messenger or agent to any of the actions shown in the pasuk. Only when the individual explanation is being used, does Hashem say, not only was an agent not used, but even the שליח that had already been appointed was not used for this particular action.

Comment: He’s not asking why it says אני ולא השליח but not אני ולא המלאך, but rather why it says אני ולא השליח yet earlier said לא על ידי שליח right before quoting the passuk of ועברתי.

Comment: @DonielF I added an explanation for the word shaliach